# LaTeX - Proper vertical spacing on multi-line parboxes with multicols

Tags: latex, typesetting, multicol

I'm trying to get two-column typesetting working, with a list of items. However, that list has elements that are either one or two lines, i.e.

```
Alpha
Beta
Zeta
   Alternative: Upsilon      <– (second line of the Zeta)
Gamma
   Alternative: Lambda
Epsilon
Omega
Omicron
   Alternative: Upsilon
...
```

I'd like to have this list on two columns, however I don't want the list to end with a split of a two-line item (i.e. "Alternative: xyz" should never start the second column).

My first thought is to put two-line elements into a `parbox`, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\RaggedRight
Alpha\\
Beta\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Gamma\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Lambda }
Epsilon\\
Omega\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Omicron\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
Kappa\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
Alpha\\
Beta\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Gamma\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Lambda }
Epsilon\\
Omega\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Omicron\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
Kappa\\
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
\parbox{\columnwidth}{ Zeta\\ \hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} Upsilon }
Sigma\\
Delta\\
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I've made that example longer than necessary to highlight the deficiency of this attempted solution. If you typeset this, the spacing between the elements is uneven, and it looks terrible.

I was wondering, then:

1. if there were any alternatives to using a `\parbox` that do not suffer this inconsistent typesetting.
2. if this `\parbox` solution could be altered so as to not have the inconsistent spacing between lines.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Define your macros, for example, `\colparbox` and `\Alt`.

2) Look the following code.

```
\def\colparbox#1{\strut \par \vskip -\baselineskip \nointerlineskip
   \parbox{\columnwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces#1\unskip\strut}\par}

\def\Alt{\hspace{1em} \textit{Alternative:} }

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\RaggedRight 
Alpha\\ 
Beta\\ 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
\colparbox{ Gamma\\ \Alt Lambda } 
Epsilon\\ 
Omega\\ 
\colparbox{ Omicron\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
Kappa\\ 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
Alpha\\ 
Beta\\ 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
\colparbox{ Gamma\\ \Alt Lambda } 
Epsilon\\ 
Omega\\ 
\colparbox{ Omicron\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
Kappa\\ 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
\colparbox{ Zeta\\ \Alt Upsilon } 
Sigma\\ 
Delta\\ 
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Brilliant - that works beautifully! I'm very much looking forward to figuring out what all that means. ;) Thank you.